# Using the same database by two different projects

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

In my new work, they have two ASP.net projects. Both projects are using the same MS SQL Database. Each project has a different developing team and end users. And each project has its own tables, and there are a common tables which both projects reads/writes data, and sometimes they use this common tables to send information to each other. i.e one system insert record, the other system update a flag in this record which means 'Yeah I can see it', and update some fields, then the first system catch the data ... etc.

My first question: Is this a good design, what are the disadvantages ?

In the other hand my opinion to split the database into two databases, one for each project, and make communications between them be through web services.

My second question: which approach is the best practice, and why ?

Comment: I would not split - you have to synchronize users afterwards, you have to synchronize any related common data (you cannot span FK relationships over multiple databases), you may lose sync while restoring data in emergency cases and so on.

Comment: I would personally split out the the interaction with DB into its own project, and have both projects reference this project in order to keep consistency across them. I would assume that when ever you are sharing something across two projects you keep them shared

Comment: what's the size? we're talking about applications used across the globe by thousands of people that require redundancy and availability and... or maybe a couple of applications used in lan by less than hundred people? is the additional layer (the wcf) worth the effort? what's the benefit you expect from the additional layer? no, 'is best practice' is not a valid answer because best practices are general rules that MUST be evaluated and not blindly applied.

Comment: The two applications are running in intranet by less that fifty users.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is any problem of having two different projects sharing a common database.
Instead of splitting database into two separate databases , I would suggest have single database only and create a third separate WCF project.
This WCF project will have only one purpose that is act as database layer , so all the database queries will be written in that service and asp.net projects will consume it.

Advantage of this approach is that all the queries will be centralized and there will not be any duplication of queries.Also in future if any new Module comes in the system like desktop application or Mobile application then there is no need to put large efforts in database queries.
Same queries can be used in all places, so maintenance will be simpler.

Comment: I would use WebApi over WCF, easier IMHO

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any problem with having a database common for two projects.I mean, even in a single project, there are so many users updating the same table at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

don't see major drawbacks to the approach. Personally i would prefer database table prefixing like

```
project1_sometbale
project2_sometable
common_sometbale
```

Comment: table schema would be a safer approach imho. with separate schema is quick and simple to limit user of application A to its schema + the common schema without access to the schema of application B. also all the objects have the schema as prefix.