# Multi domains for one project or multi domains for multi projects

Tags: model-view-controller, subdomain, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm planning to make the graduate project about the e-commerce site using ASP.Net Core 2 MVC and SQL Server, but currently, I have some troubles:

Suppose I have two domain and sub-domain: domain.com and manage.domain.com. The domain.com will like the normal e-commerce site which allows customer go to browse, search, and buy the products. The manage.domain.com will only for staff to log in and do their stuff like manage staff, order, etc.

My questions are:
Is there possible to manage two domains on one MVC project or I have to split them up? If it is possible, then how can I manage it just in one MVC project?

If I have to split them up to two projects: one for e-commerce, one for staff, then should I create the WebAPI to connect as a data layer to communicate the projects with the same database as the suggestion of [Sagar Shirke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31401877/4737343)?

Are there any other approaches to my problems? Any comments and idea will be very very appreciated.
Thanks for reading my problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about this some more I think you are taking the wrong approach.

Why don't you look at using a premade framework with an admin template page to manage typical admin task (users, passwords, custom data, etc.) ?

Instead of using a subdomain like `sub-domain: domain.com`, you could use `domain.com/admin`.

Here is an [link to **ASP.NET Boilerplate** templates.](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Samples)  I would recommend you look at the simple todo task examples and see if this is concept is what you want.  Using the free **Module Zero** admin page templates to develop quickly.  I would make sure you do the tutorials and read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. At first, I'm intending to make the domain.com/admin for staff management only, but I don't know whether MVC can suitable for doing that or not. I mean if the admin manages something like the product, the domain will be `domain.com/admin/product/detail/1`. It seems very complex and I don't know how to config something like that in the MVC routes. 
Anyway, your reply opens my mind to another approach. I very appreciate that and for your effort of finding the solution, I will make this as accept answer whether I don't know it will actually work.

Thank you!.

Comment: Make a special page for staff with a special controller `domain.com/staffadmin` or something like that.  You need to spend some time understanding routing and controllers and it will be much simpler than you think.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great [tutorial](http://benjii.me/2015/02/subdomain-routing-in-asp-net-mvc/) on how to use subdomains.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try it.

Comment: Upvoted. But seem not solving my problem directly. So I will wait for other comments/ideas.